# How to use condition to check a child-class inside a parent-class method, if the child-class is in other py script?

Tags: python

I have a parent class in a parent.py

```py
class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def some_function(self):
    if self.__class__ is Child_One:
      pass # do something
    elif self.__class__ is Child_Two:
      pass # do other things
```

Then I have another child_one.py and child_two.py which contains similar codes:

```py
from .parent import Parent

class Child_One(Parent):
  def child_function(self):
    self.some_function()
```

Before I separated `Child_One` and `Child_Two` from parent.py, the function works fine. But since I moved the two-child classes into other scripts for better code maintenance, the two conditions would be comparing an undefined object, which is invalid.
Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: What about using `isinstanceof`? I think your code ends in a cyclic dependency.. (to make a child you need Parent, to make a Parent, you need child)

Comment: Yes. I was thinking this would keep on looping in the import call. Is it a good practice to build Parent and Child class inside the same script?

Answer (score 1):

Wile there are indeed technical ways to do exactly what you ask for, those are actually the wrong solutions to the wrong problem.

The **real** problem here is that your parent class is depending on it's own child classes. This is a **major** design issue - a parent class should not know anything about its children (nothing hard-coded at least). Also, the reason you have this dependency (doing typechecking for type-dependent behaviour) is *another* design flaw - the very basis of OO is to replace those by polymorphic dispatch (most often method calls).

IOW, you want to implement a stub "do something" in your base class:

```
class Parent(object):
    def do_something_special(self):
        pass
```

Then implement it in your child classes (moving the relevant code from `Parent.some_function`):

```
class ChildOne(Parent):
    def do_something_special(self):
        # do something

class ChildTwo(Parent):
    def do_something_special(self):
        # do something else
```

and finally refactor `Parent.some_function()`:

```
def some_function(self):
    # this will invoke the proper subclass implementation
    self.do_something_special()
```

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for the advice. In this case, should I implement this function for each child-class instead setting this up in a parent-class? Thanks.

Comment: @TobiasTo there's no possible one-size-fits-all answer to this - it depends on what this method is actually doing. You __want__ to make sure this method can be called on all child classes of course - that's the whole point of OO polymorphci dispatch (same API, possibly different implementation). Now ff it's only some "extra" class-specific code that only exist for a couple child classes, having a no-op version defined in the base class (like in my example) and only overridding where necessary is the obvious simple solution (....)

Comment: @TobiasTo (...) If OTHO all child class really must do something and only a child class can possibly know what it has to do, then you may want to define your base class as an [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) and `do_something_special` as an `abstractmethod`, so child classes MUST provide proper implementation.